# C# serialPort.Open() failed or need a very long time to work

Tags: c#, bluetooth, serial-port

I am trying to use a Bluetooth serial port for 2 days and I need to wait 20 minutes to 1 hour to have the serial port actually open...

`serialPort.Open()` failed with this exception (the port exists) :

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.IO.Ports.dll
> Élément introuvable. : 'COM5'

I realized that it could work if I waited so long because I left my computer with a breakpoint during my lunch, and continue the execution after.
I have tried to use different libraries with always the same result.
I have tried different parameters for baud-rate etc...
Of course, the device (an HC-05) is correctly paired and connected, I have tried it with an android app and it works. it also works when the port finally accepts to open.
The Port Name I pass is the good one, the port is actually created when the device is paired and connected (it pops in the device manager)
My windows install is fresh so, no ghost serial ports.
the code is pretty simple :

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort
{
    BaudRate = 115200
    PortName = BluetoothPortName;
};

while (!_serialPort.IsOpen) // because I want it to finally succeed!
{ 
    try
    {
        _serialPort.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
        Logger.Error(ToString(), $"Failed to open SerialPort : {ex.Message}");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Each side of the COM interface can only be accessed by one party at any time. This means: If someone uses one end of the connection or forgot to close the connection, no other party will be able to use that end until the connection is closed (or timed out). Based on what you wrote, I guess your time-out period is set to one hour.

Comment: @Xaver, thank you for your comment!
I have tried to set :
_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;
_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 200;
before opening the port, but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution while SerialPort.Open() is hanging without "Exception".

```
    private bool _Connect(SerialPort sp , int timeout_ms)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() => sp.Open()).Wait(timeout_ms);
            if (!sp.IsOpen) 
            { 
                throw new TimeoutException("Port.Open Timeout"); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //sp.Close();
            return (sp.IsOpen);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return (sp.IsOpen);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**